# Does 'during the summer' imply how long does the activity take or when does the activity happen?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

[image]

This exercise is from [BC Learn English Web site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/adverbials-of-time) I don't understand why it should only be in the 'when' column (according to the answer key)

During on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/during):

a)From the beginning to the end of a particular period

b) at some time between the beginning and the end of a period

During on [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/during):

a) from the beginning to the end of a period of time

b) at some point in a period of time

So I think it should be in both *When* and *How long* columns. But the answer key says it should only be in the When column. It should even be in the third column depending on contex, I believe. For instance:

'Every summer I visit my grandma, during my holiday'.

Comment: [Does "during the summer" **imply how long the activity takes**]

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Longman gives a sentence using *during the summer* as an example of their Definition (a), but in fact the exact duration of 'the summer' is somewhat vague (the meteorological summer? a school or university's summer vacation?), so the phrase is very often used in the sense of both (b) definitions - 'at some time during the summer months'.

Your example sentence uses *every summer,* which is different from *during the summer*.

Comment: I would expect that a pension to be paid 'during my lifetime' to continue until I die, but I agree it can be a vague usage.

Answer (score 0):

**during** can mean "in a specified time-period":

> During the autumn months, the municipality will periodically collect fallen leaves by neighborhood. See the schedule posted on the website.
>
> When is the eclipse supposed to happen? -- I don't remember, sometime during the summer.
>
> Elephants will dig for water during times of drought.

Or **during** can mean "for the entire duration of a time-period":

> The surviving spouse will continue to receive benefits during their lifetime.
>
> The air-conditioning system is kept off during the winter.

The meaning is made clear by context and the nature of the verb phrase.